# Compare first array value with second array key and replace value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two array. first one is multi dimensional array. second array contains key and value pair. now my goal is i want to check `second index` of every array from first array value to check that value in second array as key exist? if yes then that first array value need to replace with second array value.

```
$first_array = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2012/12
            [1] => 
            [2] => "SI"
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
   )
[1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2012/12
            [1] => 
            [2] => "MB"
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
   )
)


$second_array = array(
["MB"] => "WE",
["SI"] => "SA",
["SO"] => "SA",
)
```

my output should look like this

```
$first_array = Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2012/12
                [1] => 
                [2] => "SA"
                [3] => 
                [4] => 
                [5] => 
       )
    [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2012/12
                [1] => 
                [2] => "WE"
                [3] => 
                [4] => 
                [5] => 
       )
    )
```

Comment: This is really easy. Foreach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go with simple `foreach` loop and `if`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/777102)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$first_array = Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            0 => "2012/12",
            1 => "",
            2 => "SI",
            3 => "",
            4 => "",
            5 => "",
   ),
1 => Array
        (
            0 => "2012/12",
            1 => "",
            2 => "MB",
            3 => "",
            4 => "",
            5 => "",
   )
);


$second_array = array(
"MB" => "WE",
"SI" => "SA",
"SO" => "SA",
);

foreach($first_array as $key1 => $data)
{
    if(isset($second_array[$data[2]]))
    {
        $first_array[$key1][2]=$second_array[$data[2]];
    }

}
print_r($first_array);
```

Comment: *i want to check second index of every array*

Comment: @splash58 Oops sorry i skipped that.

Comment: @splash58 I have updated my post. Thanks for reminding ... :)

Answer (score 0):

What about foreach?

```
foreach($first_array as &$v)
{
    //$v[2] = isset($second_array[$v[2]]) ? $second_array[$v[2]] : $v[2];

    if(isset($second_array[$v[2]))
        $v[2] = $second_array[$v[2]];
}

print_r($first_array);
```

Comment: A ternary operator isn't a good idea here. With a simple `if` you don't have to to re-affect the same value.